# Simple HTML Image Slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I'm looking for a very simple and straightforward image slideshow. No extra features just a selection of images fading in and out. Potrait and Landscapes need to be shown in their full size without any scrollbars being enabled. I managed to find this one:

```html
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fadeSlideShow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('#slideshow').fadeSlideShow();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="slideshow">
    <img src="../images/large/nature/BokehPlant1.jpg" width="640" height="480" border="0" alt="" /> <!-- This is the last image in the slideshow -->
    <img src="../images/large/nature/BokehPlant2.jpg" width="640" height="480" border="0" alt="" />
    <img src="../images/large/nature/BokehPlant3.jpg" width="640" height="480" border="0" alt="" />
    <img src="../images/large/nature/RusticLeaf1.jpg" width="640" height="480" border="0" alt="" /> <!-- This is the first image in the slideshow -->
</div>
</body>
```

However it doesn't seem to want to work though. All it does it renders the images on after another.

Apologies in advance I haven't played with HTML in a while and I don't have much experience regarding JavaScript.

Many thanks in Advance!
Harry

Comment: Your code snippet is useless without us being able to see `fadeSlideshow.js`.

Comment: fadeSlideshow.js has no documentation?

Comment: Hi, I think you are trying to use this http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/fadeinslideshow.htm, please follow the documentation for fadeslideshow.js

Comment: I suggest you use `bootsrap carousel` its really simple.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this might help you

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
           <div id="slideshow">
      <div>
            <img src="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/pool.jpg" style="width:550px;height:250px" />
      </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/cave.jpg" style="width:550px;height:250px" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/fruits.jpg" style="width:550px;height:250px" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/dog.jpg" style="width:550px;height:250px" />
        </div>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     SlideShow();
});

function SlideShow() {
    $('#slideshow > div:gt(0)').hide();

    setInterval(function () {
        $('#slideshow > div:first')
        .fadeOut(6000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(6000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
    }, 6000);
}
```

LINK
    http://jsbin.com/duyoyuyiwu/1/edit?html,js,output